# Having problem with displaying text on pdf generated in Salesforce Visual Page

Tags: css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Hope someone can help me with this. Having a problem with displaying text on pdf in Salesforce Visual Pages.

The Salesforce visual page is displaying a .gif form image from static resources, and I am trying to line up the input from text variables with spaces on the form.

Just as an example I have included last name. The text is either displaying above the image or below the image when rendered as pdf.

Here is an example of my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" renderAs="PDF">


<head>
<style>
lastname {
position: relative; 
left: 55px; 
top: 407px; 
width: 7in; 
font-size: 10pt; 
line-height: 14pt;
}
</style>
</head> 

<body>

<apex:variable var="my_last_name" value="{Lastname}" />

<!-- <td width="40%" style="padding-top:100px;padding-bottom:100px"> </td> -->
<apex:outputText style="padding-top:100px;padding-bottom:100px" value="{!my_last_name}" escape="false" />

<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Form1)}" style="position:center; margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0; width:auto; height:900px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; background-size:contain; page-break-after:always; font-size:1.1em; color: #00008B;" />

</body>

</html>
</apex:page>
```

If you could provide any pointers for a new Salesforce developer that would be great!

Comment: Have also tried:

Comment: <div class="box">
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Form1)}" style="margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0; width:auto; height:900px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; background-size:contain; page-break-after:always; font-size:1.1em; color: #00008B;" />
<p class="top-left"><apex:outputText value="{!my_last_name}" escape="false" /></p>
</div>

Comment: But still not working. Code above just displays text in top left corner above image.

Comment: Was able to fix this by putting code in table, and then using margin-left to move across.